# Crystal Date Parameter for last year

Tags: date, parameters, crystal-reports

I have tried using this formula with a date parameter. It works for the other 11 months but not the 12th month. Could some one please let me know what additional code I need to add to the formula. 
     If {?End Date} = 12/14/13
I want the formula to = 12/31/12
This is what I have been using to make it work for the other 11 months. 
     Date(year({?End Date})-1, month({?End Date})+1,1) - 1
I receive an error that the month needs to be 1 - 12. 
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
CDate(Year(DateAdd ('yyyy',-1,CurrentDate)),Month(DateAdd ('M',0,CurrentDate)),31)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the last day of the month of the previous year:

```
DateAdd("m", 1, DateTime( Year({immaster.timestmp})-1, Month({immaster.timestmp}), 1, 0,0,0 )) - 1
```